# Hydro for Ubuntu Precise armhf on new kernel

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm intending to test the following: run Ubuntu Precise armhf with ROS Hydro with kernel 3.10. Having read that Hydro is supported up to Raring (kernel 3.8), I think that my combination will result in a non-working situation. Any suggestions ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141221/hydro-for-ubuntu-precise-armhf-on-new-kernel/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-18**:
Ok, just did this and roscore (hydro) reports that it's "unable to contact my own server at [http://:59299]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My first assumption here is that this should work. ROS depends very strongly on libraries such as boost, and really don't care which kernel it's running on top of. In fact, most of Ubuntu cares very little about the kernel.

The error you're seeing about "cannot contact my own master" is a network/loopback configuration issue and not related to the kernel. Try pinging your machine's hostname to confirm, then try adding your hostname to one of the loopback addresses in /etc/hosts

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-18**:
My hostname is added to /etc/hosts. The ping is successful, although it delivers only 1 ping. After this it does nothing but hanging in there:

64 bytes from  (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.135 ms
^C
---  ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.135/0.135/0.135/0.000 ms

The ^C is given by me after waiting more than 5 minutes.
What about the server address? When I ran Groovy, the address was 11311, now it is 59299. Is this usual ?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-18**:
Tested roscore/ping localhost again. Via ssh, it only pings once which is successful. Direct on system in X terminal, ping goes fine. Via ssh, roscore starts but after message "Usage < 1GB" nothing. Only way to stop = kill PID. Via X terminal, after long wait it again "cannot contact own server".

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-19**:
It sounds like you have some network driver or network setup problems on you machine. You'll have to get those sorted out before anything that depends on networking (including ROS) will work.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-20**:
which python version goes with either groovy or hydro ? The running version is 2.7.3

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-20**:
Python 2.7.3 is fine.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-20**:
As a side note, roscore should be starting up on port 11311; not 59299. Are you sure you have your ROS_MASTER_URI set correctly?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-20**:
Yes, the port number is what I was wondering about as well. Was used to 11311. Good question..will look at that.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-03-26**:
Tried the same combination (kernel 3.10.18 and hydro) on an x86 (actually old AthlonXP). No problem, either with or without real-time (xenomai). Standard installation Ubuntu 12.04. On armhf still a no go.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-26**:
This could still be a kernel issue with the specific network drivers for your board. The realtime kernels tend to move a number of interrupt handlers to preemptible threads, and this can occasionally cause additional overhead or locking problems, particularly on less-tested platforms such as ARM.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-26**:
I would suggest (1) making sure that your hostname and /etc/hosts are set up properly so that your hostname resolves to a loopback address, and that it's pingable, and (2) try to figure out why the ROS core is running on a non-standard port.